# What is my matlab plot doing?

Tags: matlab, graph

[image: Matlab plot]

I'm trying to graph few basic graphs, time vs velocity, time vs acceleration, velocity vs acceleration, but I don't understand why these numbers are appearing on every graph. I've tried changing the labels via several methods, but it doesn't seem to make them disappear.

```
clc
clear

disp('Jack Abdo');
disp('Engr Course 297 12441');
disp('Matlab Homework 8 problem #4');
disp('This script graphs output data from a UDP');

ourinput = [0 0];
ourinput(1) = input('Please enter the beginning time.');
ourinput(2) = input('Please enter the ending time.');

time = [ourinput(1):5:ourinput(2)]
velocity = 0.00001*time.^3 - 0.00488*time.^2 + 0.75795*time + 181.3566
acceleration = 3 - 0.000062*velocity.^2

subplot(5,1,1);
plot(time,velocity);
xlabel(time);
ylabel(velocity);
grid;
title('Velocity vs Time');
set(gca,'XTick',0:30:120)
set(gca,'YTick',180:10:220)

subplot(5,1,2);
plot(time,acceleration);
xlabel(time);
ylabel(acceleration);
grid;
title('Acceleration vs Time');
set(gca,'XTick',0:30:120)
set(gca,'YTick',0:5:1)

subplot(5,1,1);
plot(velocity, acceleration);
xlabel(velocity);
ylabel(acceleration);
grid;
title('Acceleration vs Velocity');
axis auto;
```

Comment: What wound up being incorrect was that I forgot the quotes around time, acceleration and velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is really important to write codes carefully.

i will point out some stuff-

```
velocity = 0.00001*time.^3 - 0.00488*time.^2 + 0.75795*time + 181.3566
```

if you are multiplying an array with a scalar, use a `.*` sign, so `0.75795.*time`

since labels are supposed to be strings it should be `xlabel('Velocity');` i believe otherwise it will put the whole array velocity as `xlabel` and this is causing your problems

you are dividing your figure into 5 subplots even though you have 3 subplots, so most of your window is empty. make it `subplot(3,1,1)`

now as someone who has plotted a lot of time-series, i would suggest to not predefine the time axis. try using `set(gca,'XTick',[min(time):5:max(time)]);`

put semicolon after each statement unless u want output explicitly.
anyways this is what you might have been looking for. please go through your codes carefully

```
disp('Jack Abdo');
disp('Engr Course 297 12441');
disp('Matlab Homework 8 problem #4');
disp('This script graphs output data from a UDP');

ourinput = [0 0];
ourinput(1) = input('Please enter the beginning time.');
ourinput(2) = input('Please enter the ending time.');

time = [ourinput(1):5:ourinput(2)];
velocity = 0.00001.*time.^3 - 0.00488.*time.^2 + 0.75795.*time + 181.3566;
acceleration = 3 - 0.000062.*velocity.^2;

subplot(3,1,1);
plot(time,velocity);
xlabel('time');
ylabel('velocity');
grid;
title('Velocity vs Time');
set(gca,'XTick',0:30:120);
set(gca,'YTick',180:10:220);

subplot(3,1,2);
plot(time,acceleration);
xlabel('time');
ylabel('acceleration');
grid;
title('Acceleration vs Time');
set(gca,'XTick',0:30:120);
set(gca,'YTick',0:5:1);

subplot(3,1,3);
plot(velocity, acceleration);
xlabel('velocity');
ylabel('acceleration');
grid;
title('Acceleration vs Velocity');
axis auto;
```